# Using amp-list to create dynamic amp-carousel in AMP4HTML

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I want to use amp-list to create a dynamic amp-carousel for AMP4Email.

I built out a template that passes validation [here](https://github.com/randyjensen/amp-email-templates/blob/master/templates/1.html), but when putting it into https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/, the carousel doesn't work.

Is this not possible with AMP4Email? It appears to work fine in AMP generally based on [this](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/14689).

The part of the code that renders the carousel

```
<amp-list src="https://amp-templates.com/templates/api/1.json"
  layout="fixed-height"
  height="400">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <amp-carousel id="links-carousel"
      height="400"
      layout="fixed-height"
      type="slides">
        {{#default}}
          {{#images}}
            <div>
              <a href="{{link}}" class="carousel-link">
                <amp-img
                  class="contain"
                  layout="fill"
                  src="{{image}}"
                  alt="photo courtesy of Unsplash"></amp-img>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <p>{{description}}</p>
                  </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          {{/images}}
        {{/default}}
    </amp-carousel>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

Comment: Have you encountered errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "doesn't work", are you referring to the carousel not showing up?

Your code, as-is, won't work in the AMP email playground (or in an actual AMP email), because the src of your list, "https://amp-templates.com/templates/api/1.json" is not sending back the right CORS headers in its response. Try opening the console and network requests, and you should be able to see exactly what I mean.

Since the  src is remote, the AMP specs enforce a lot of extra security requirements that you must adhere to in order for the json file to be fetched. The headers for the email playground can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/security-requirements#amp_for_email_playground), whereas a more complete list of required headers is [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md#cors-security-in-amp).

I was able to confirm that this issue affected your code by hosting up the JSON myself, and adding this to my htaccess:

```
# AMP
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "amp@gmail.dev"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"
Header add access-control-expose-headers "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"
```

I threw it up on a temporary host, at "https://fjas298401cxj.000webhostapp.com/amptemplates-api-1.json", which you can replace your  src with to verify.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txhCX.png)

Comment: That was it! Thanks Joshua. Added those headers and everything is working now.